# How to find the shortest distance between two line segments capturing the sign values with python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, binary-search, kdtree

I have a `pandas dataframe` of the form:

```
    benchmark_x benchmark_y ref_point_x ref_point_y
0   525039.140  175445.518  525039.145  175445.539
1   525039.022  175445.542  525039.032  175445.568
2   525038.944  175445.558  525038.954  175445.588
3   525038.855  175445.576  525038.859  175445.576
4   525038.797  175445.587  525038.794  175445.559
5   525038.689  175445.609  525038.679  175445.551
6   525038.551  175445.637  525038.544  175445.577
7   525038.473  175445.653  525038.459  175445.594
8   525038.385  175445.670  525038.374  175445.610
9   525038.306  175445.686  525038.289  175445.626
```

I am trying to find the shortest distance from the line to the benchmark such that if the line is above the benchmark the distance is positive and if it is below the benchmark the distance is negative. See image below:

[image]

I used the `KDTree` from `scipy` like so:

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
tree=KDTree(df[["benchmark_x", "benchmark_y"]])
test = df.apply(lambda row: tree.query(row[["ref_point_x", "ref_point_y"]]), axis=1)
test=test.apply(pd.Series, index=["distance", "index"])
```

This seems to work except that it fails to capture the negative values as a result that the line is below the benchmark.

Comment: Which distance measure do you want to use? Euclidean, Manhattan, ..?

Comment: quick nearest-neighbor lookup

Comment: That is not a measure. nearest-neighbor also requires a distance measure... Please look it up and clarify your question, as now it is difficult for me and others to help

Comment: its a distance. it does what I want, it only fails to capture the negative values

Comment: Again, it is not. Not trying to be a wise guy here, but it is an algorithm. I looked up KDtree and it clearly has a distance measure as argument. The default is Minkowski, that is the answer I was looking for. Anyway, it seems like you already have an answer below.

Comment: the answer does not seem to work on the complete dataset. Do you have an approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
# recreating your example
columns = "benchmark_x benchmark_y ref_point_x ref_point_y".split(" ")
data = """525039.140  175445.518  525039.145  175445.539
525039.022  175445.542  525039.032  175445.568
525038.944  175445.558  525038.954  175445.588
525038.855  175445.576  525038.859  175445.576
525038.797  175445.587  525038.794  175445.559
525038.689  175445.609  525038.679  175445.551
525038.551  175445.637  525038.544  175445.577
525038.473  175445.653  525038.459  175445.594
525038.385  175445.670  525038.374  175445.610
525038.306  175445.686  525038.289  175445.626"""
data = [float(x) for x in data.replace("\n"," ").split(" ") if len(x)>0]
arr = np.array(data).reshape(-1,4)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=columns)

# adding your two new columns to the df
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
tree=KDTree(df[["benchmark_x", "benchmark_y"]])
df["distance"], df["index"] = tree.query(df[["ref_point_x", "ref_point_y"]])
```

Now to compare if one line is above the other or not, we have to evaluate y at the same x position. Therefore we need to interpolate the y points for the x positions of the other line.

```
df = df.sort_values("ref_point_x") # sorting is required for interpolation
xy_refpoint = df[["ref_point_x", "ref_point_y"]].values
df["ref_point_y_at_benchmark_x"] = np.interp(df["benchmark_x"], xy_refpoint[:,0], xy_refpoint[:,1])
```

And finally your criterium can be evaluated and applied:

```
df["distance"] = np.where(df["ref_point_y_at_benchmark_x"] < df["benchmark_y"], -df["distance"], df["distance"])
# or change the < to <,>,<=,>= as you wish
```

[image]
[image]